# How can I build a year-round aromatic garden in Zone 10a?

Tags: flowering, evergreens

I am building an aromatic garden and looking for some drought-resistant **fragrant evergreen** shrubs/trees to give me year-round interest.

Winter interest:

1. Osmanthus sweet tea olive blooms in October - March.
2. Michelia champaca blooms in January - March.
3. Daphne odora blooms in Feb - March.

Spring interest:

1. Camellia blooms in January - May.
2. Cherry laurel blooms in February - April.
3. Sarcococca ruscifolia blooms in March-April.
4. Rhododendron/Azaleas blooms in March-May.

Summer - fall interest:

1. Star jasmine blooms in May - June. ​
2. Gardenias blooms in May - July.
3. Some deciduous roses and chrysanthemums.

I am in USDA Zone 10a: to -1.1 °C (30 °F), and all plants are planted outdoor in-ground.

Can anyone help me to find some summer & fall blooming **fragrant evergreen** plants? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few suggestions, all from [this page](https://www.monrovia.com/be-inspired/753-2.html).

- [Banana Shrub, Michelia figo](https://www.monrovia.com/banana-shrub.html): fragrant, banana-scented flowers. Heaviest blooming in spring, but blooms all season.
- [Night Blooming Jessamine, Cestrum nocturnum](https://www.monrovia.com/night-blooming-jessamine.html): small, not very showy, fragrant flowers at night during the summer
- [Arabian Jasmine, Jasminum sambac](https://www.monrovia.com/arabian-jasmine.html): fragrant flowers from summer into fall, or year round in "warm climates" (unclear whether that includes zone 10a, but probably not as they mention the tropics elsewhere in the description)
- [Gilt Edge Silverberry, Elaeagnus x ebbingei 'Gilt Edge'](https://www.monrovia.com/gilt-edge-silverberry.html): tiny, fragrant, silvery flowers in fall

Answer (score 1):

A great perfumed bloom is white butterfly ginger, Hedychium colonarium. In zone 8 it begins blooming in July, don't know about Z-10. Typically 5 ft tall when blooming. In Z-8 it dies back in winter but is very hardy and trouble free. Scent as strong as gardenia but lasts much longer. Another hardy scented bloom favorite of mine is 4 O'clock, Many gardeners are not impressed, maybe because they are so easy to grow.  Invasive in zone 8 . The individual flowers do not have strong scent but several bushes will have a hundred new blooms each afternoon and will be noticeable. Here they are a favorite of hummingbird moths ( in the evening), an interesting visitor. Zone 8 they bloom from late June to fall.